# spring security data with index issues

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

trying to use method level security with spring data security.

I have created a sample repo 
https://github.com/jayasai470/spring-data-security-sample/

when @Indexed is commented everything works fine and I can see in mongo debug logs that
for the spel query @Query("{tenantId: ?#{principal.tenantId}}") tenantId is properly injected

but when I try to include the @Indexed annotation server fails to start. Mongo template threw an exception with Authentication object is null

```
 // my entity class
@Data
@Document(collection = "userprofiles")
public class UserProfile {

@Id
@Field("_id")
private String id;

@Email(message = "not a valid email")
@Indexed(unique = true, name = "email_1", background = true)
private String email;

private String tenantId;
}

 //repository
@Repository
public interface UserProfileRepository extends 
  PagingAndSortingRepository<UserProfile, String> {

UserProfile findOneByEmail(String email);

@Query("{tenantId: ?#{principal.tenantId}}")
List<UserProfile> findAllByTenantId();
}

// registered a bean of SecurityEvaluationContextExtension
public class MongoSecurityEvaluationContextExtension extends 
 SecurityEvaluationContextExtension {

@Override
public String getExtensionId() {
 return "security";
}

@Override
public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
 return Collections.singletonMap("principal", (UserProfile) 
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal());
 }
}

//web security config
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public SecurityEvaluationContextExtension 
 securityEvaluationContextExtension() {
    return new MongoSecurityEvaluationContextExtension();
 }

}
```

Above code works fine if we remove the @indexed annotation. if indexing is enabled then server fails to start

below is the stack-trace

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Factory method 'mongoTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Authentication object cannot be null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 67 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Authentication object cannot be null
    at org.springframework.security.access.expression.SecurityExpressionRoot.<init>(SecurityExpressionRoot.java:61) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.data.repository.query.SecurityEvaluationContextExtension$1.<init>(SecurityEvaluationContextExtension.java:108) ~[spring-security-data-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.data.repository.query.SecurityEvaluationContextExtension.getRootObject(SecurityEvaluationContextExtension.java:108) ~[spring-security-data-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.spel.ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider$EvaluationContextExtensionAdapter.<init>(ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.java:369) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.spel.ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.lambda$toAdapters$2(ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.java:159) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:352) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.data.spel.ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.toAdapters(ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.java:160) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.spel.ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.access$000(ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.java:65) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.spel.ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider$ExtensionAwarePropertyAccessor.<init>(ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.java:182) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.spel.ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.getEvaluationContext(ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.java:110) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.spel.ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.getEvaluationContext(ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.java:64) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.getEvaluationContext(BasicPersistentEntity.java:528) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity.getEvaluationContext(BasicMongoPersistentEntity.java:182) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.getEvaluationContextForProperty(MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.java:525) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.pathAwareIndexName(MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.java:584) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.createIndexDefinition(MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.java:443) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.createIndexDefinitionHolderForProperty(MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.java:213) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.potentiallyAddIndexForProperty(MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.java:145) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.lambda$resolveIndexForEntity$1(MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.java:129) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:355) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.resolveIndexForEntity(MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.java:128) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.resolveIndexFor(MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.java:104) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.checkForAndCreateIndexes(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:140) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.checkForIndexes(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:130) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.<init>(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:95) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.<init>(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:72) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.<init>(MongoTemplate.java:275) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDbFactoryDependentConfiguration.mongoTemplate(MongoDbFactoryDependentConfiguration.java:63) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 68 common frames omitted


    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please show us the relevant code here. Linking to a repository elsewhere is nice for additional information but question should be self sustained. Also what is the exact exception you are getting, including the stack trace.

Comment: @JensSchauder I have modified my question, please take a look at it and let me know if any additional information is needed. Thanks

Comment: @JensSchauder how can i re-open this question ?

Comment: I voted for reopening it. I think it needs 3 votes. Not much you can do about it.

Comment: This might be this issue https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1625 Since there exists an internal PR there should be a SNAPSHOT version available that you could use to verify this theory.

Comment: @JensSchauder Thanks for the info, 2.1.14.DATACMNS-1625-SNAPSHOT is not yet released in the artifactory https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/

Comment: i still have the same problem with @CompoundIndex innotations with spring boot 2.2.8, did you solve it?